# Python openCV - compiled .exe file does not work on a different computer

Tags: python, opencv, windows-7, pyinstaller, video-capture

I have written a program which uses openCV to analyze some videos. I have written the program on one computer, created an exe file using `pyinstaller` and opened it on the other computer.
I used the following command with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn --onedir analyzeVid.py
```

The `--hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn` part is to sort another problem I had...

I ran the .exe on three different computers - two have windows10 and the .exe file works perfectly on them. The 3rd computer has windows7 and when I try to open a video file I get the following message:

> [ WARN:0] global c:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-builed-c213r8zm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp <696> CvCapture_MSMF::initStream Failed to set mediaType <stream 1, <1280x720 @ 14.9909> MFVideoFormat_RGB24 [unsupported media type]

I saw in some other sources that the following might help:
`vidcap = VideoCapture(vidPath, CAP_DSHOW)`, but when I try to get the total amount of frames (on the original computer) I get 0.0 which is obviously wrong, but I tried to run an .exe file with this line on the 3rd computer (the windows7 one) as well (and obviously it didn't work there either).

I also tried with `vidcap = VideoCapture(vidPath, CAP_ANY)`. With this I get good results on the two first computers, but get the same error on the windows7 one.

I've created a short code and I wrote where I get the error:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
from cv2 import VideoCapture, CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT, CAP_ANY
from os import path
import datetime

def loadFile():
    vid = QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(None, "Select Video", filter = "mp4(*.mp4)") 
    if (vid[0]!=""):
        vid = str(vid[0])
    else:
        vid = None
    return(loadVidTimes(vid))
        
def loadVidTimes(vid):
    if (vid is not None):
        vidcap = VideoCapture(vid, apiPreference = CAP_ANY) #Here's where I get the error on win7, regardless of the apiPreference
        totalFrames = vidcap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        creation_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(vid))
        return(totalFrames, creation_time)

print(loadFile())
```

I guess the issue comes from the difference between OS... Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: you've kept your code a secret. can't help without seeing that. remember, [mre].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I've added a short code example to show where I get the error. This is obviously not all of the code, but this the problematic section.